# Perform an action on root change in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a way to customize what happens when I update the root in NERDTree (shift + c) ? I'm trying to figure out how to save a session with a given name after I update root in NERDTree.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in hook, but you can override the plugin's mapping and insert your hook:

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> C :echo "hooked!"<Bar>call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap('C')<CR>
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me. Even when I remove nerdtree#invokeKeyMap('C'), it still works.

Comment: Interesting. I use the latest dev version from http://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree; also, try checking whether the mapping is active via `:verb nmap C` (in the NERDTree buffer).

Comment: Just tried it out and it still shows same as before. I updated my .vimrc file and tried directly in vim. any ideas?